# Tentativa de inserir valor via "attr"

Tags: javascript, iframe, atributos

Estou criando uma página que fará uma simulação de um site na versão mobile.

Após preencher o campo URL, o site aparecerá em um "Iframe".

O problema é que quando insiro a URL no campo, alguns sites funcionam e outros não. Estou passando o valor do campo via "attr". Alguém já passou por isso ou saberia me ajudar? Vejam o código:

```js
function simula(){
  var x = document.getElementById('campo1').value;
  $('iframe').attr('src', x);
}
```

```css
#campo1{width: 300px; padding: 10px;}
.bt{padding: 10px 40px; background: #000; color: #fff; border: 0px; cursor: pointer;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p align="center">
     <input type="text" name="campo1" id="campo1" placeholder="Inserir URL"><br><br>
     <button class="bt" onclick="simula()">TESTAR</button>
<br><br><br>
     <iframe name="Iframe" class="frame"  width="800" height="400"></iframe>
    </p>
```

Comment: Ola @renato, Bem vindo ao SOpt, antes de começar de uma olhada em nosso [Tour]. --- Vale apena você adicionar as seguintes informações, **Sites testados** e **Em quais funcionou**, mas posso te adiantar que me parece que você esta tendo problemas com o header de resposta `X-Frame-Options` e não com seu código, aqui no SOpt, já existe respostas falando sobre ele, vou colocar uma aqui como possível duplicada =D

Comment: Prezado, não são todos os sites que aceitam ser carregados em iframes.